# How to categorize content in Django ? Where is the problem with my work?

Tags: python, django

I wanted to categorize my site content. Show the category titles in the menu and the contents of each category in the body. I have used these codes.

```
#urls
path('category/<slug:slug>', views.category, name="category")


#views
    
def category(request, slug):
    context = {
        "categorys": get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slug, status=True)
    }
    return render(request, "blog/category.html", context)

#models

class PostManager(models.Manager):
    def published(self):
        return self.filter(status='p')


class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="عنوان دسته بندی")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, verbose_name="آدرس")
    status = models.BooleanField(
        default=True, verbose_name="آیا نمایش داده شود؟")
    position = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="پوزیشن")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "دسته بندی"
        verbose_name_plural = "دسته بندی ها"
        ordering = ['position']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = [
        ('d', 'پیش نویس'),
        ('p', 'منتشر شده'),
    ]
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="عنوان")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, verbose_name="آدرس")
    category = models.ManyToManyField(
        Category, verbose_name="دسته بندی", related_name="postcat")
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name="توضیحات")
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(
        upload_to="imgpost", height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=None, verbose_name="تصویر")
    publish = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now, verbose_name="زمان انتشار")
    created = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="زمان ایجاد")
    updated = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=True, verbose_name="زمان بروزرسانی")
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, verbose_name="وضعیت")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "پست"
        verbose_name_plural = "پست ها"

objects = PostManager()

#template
{% for posts in categorys.postcat.published  %}
<p>
posts.title
</p>
<p>
posts.description
</p>
{%endfor%}
```

The problem is that despite the filter I have set for not displaying draft posts, that post is not displayed in the category section. If you can help. my project in [my github](https://github.com/mohamadamirnabavi/amir313)

Comment: You're only returning the category record in the context. You need to follow the relationship to get the related posts as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% for posts in categorys.postcat.published  %}
<p>
{{ posts.title }}
</p>
<p>
{{ posts.description }}
</p>
{%endfor%}
```

try this!

Answer (score 0):

We have to put this line of code in the model, the post class. It was a back fever.

```
objects = PostManager()
```